# Implementing Equals based on Hash Code

Tags: java, hash

According to equals and hashCode contract rules, is there anything wrong in the code below?

```
class Test {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        //Calculate hash
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Test other = (Test) obj;
        if(this.hashCode() == other.hashCode()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it violates the contract, if 2 objects have the same hashcode doesn't mean they are equal

Comment: I'm not sure about the need for `this.hashCode() == other.hashCode()`, as the contract should state that two objects that are `equal` should have the same `hashCode`, but I use the Apache Common library to generate them, so what would I know :P

Comment: It is a good example of how you shouldn't implement equals

Comment: Because hashcodes are always equal to 0,they will always hash to the same bucket resulting in a degenerated  linked list

Answer (score 2):

According to the hashcode / equals contract, there is nothing wrong.

But that doesn't necessarily make the code correct.  It all depends on the *required equality semantics* of the class.

For instance, if there are required to be more than 2^32 distinct states that a `Test` object could have, then this approach cannot possibly work ... because there are only 2^32 distinct values that can be returned by a `hashCode()` method.  And even in the sub 2^32 case, you are depending on the *existence* of a perfect hashing function for the class.  Finding / writing a function won't always be practical.

---

The other thing to note is that your approach is often going to be less efficient than implementing equals in the normal way.  Why?  Compare this example:

```
class Test {
    private boolean field1;
    private boolean field2;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (field1 ? 0 : 1) * 2 + (field2 ? 0 : 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Test other = (Test) obj;
        // version 1
        if(this.hashCode() == other.hashCode()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        // version 2
        if (this.field1 == other.field1 && this.field2 == other.field2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now compare the "version 1" and "version 2" fragments:

- version 1 - 2 method calls, 5 compare-and-branches and 1 multiply.
- version 2 - 0 method calls, 2 compare-and-branch and 0 multiplies.

Now the JIT compiler may optimize significantly, but in this case, the calculation of the hashcodes will probably out-weigh any saving.  Even if you cached the hashcodes (like `String` does for example) you need the conditions to be "just right" for the hashcode-based approach to be better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have concrete implementation of `hashCode` instead of "calculate hash" line, your code is correct and even will make sense for some cases.

For example, if `Test` is essentially `Boolean`, i.e. it can have only two values. Then if you define `hashCode` as:

```
 public int hashCode() {
    return value ? 1 : 0;
 }
```

Your equals method will be fully functional.

Another similar example if your `Test` class is `Integer` value object. If you return `value` as `hash`, equals will work and will be logically correct.

Base rule is that as long as you can define `hashCode` so that it covers all possible values of your class, you are good. Otherwise your `equals` implementations just does not make sense, as it can returns `true` for some logically distinct objects.

P.S. For those who say that this implementation violates equals-hashcode contract. You are totally wrong. As `equals` for this implementation works equally to `hashCode`, contract can't be violated by definition.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect because [the `hashCode` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) is not required to return distinct `int`s for all possible states of the object.

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

It is theoretically possible for two objects not to be equal to each other, but they return the same hash code.

The testing for `null`, same reference, and different class appears correct.

But instead of relying on the hash code to determine equality, you must make your own comparisons based on the object's own fields and own standards for equality.

Comment: Then what about this comment? If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Comment: The reverse is not necessarily true.  Yes, the contract for `hashCode` states that if 2 objects are `equal`, then they must return the same hash code, but the reverse is not true.  If 2 objects have the same hash code, then they are not necessarily `equal`.

Comment: If 2 objects have the same hash code, then they are not necessarily equal. But they can be equal right?

Comment: It is possible that they are equal if they have the same hash code.  But it is not required.

Comment: If there are two objects that aren't equal but return the same hash code, then your `equals` method will incorrectly return `true`.

Comment: That is as per my requirement and the way I implement hashCode(). This doesn't mean that my implementation violates contract.

Answer (score 0):

Two points.  First, don't start with `int hash = 0;`  Better to start with a positive value, say: `int hash = 17;`  That avoids the danger of multiplying your initial 0 by some input and hence losing the effect of that input on the final hash value.

Second, your explicit test for `null` is unnecessary.  Try using:

```
if (!(obj instanceOf MyType)) {
  return false;
} else {
  MyType myty = (MyType)obj;
  ...
}
```

The `instanceOf` operator will return `false` if either `obj` is null or it is not of `MyType`.